# .Net Core Docker Image cannot access database when running in docker

Tags: c#, docker

I have a dotnet core application that tries to access to the database, when I run it in visual studio it works fine (probably because of my domain authentication) but when I try to build docker image and run it with `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name console console`

I'm getting this error, but I don't really understand why?
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

The connection string looks like this: `Data Source=DBTest; Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True`

it works fine locally on my machine when I run through visual studio.

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not acces
>       sible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 0 - Access is denied.) ---> System.Com
>       ponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied

Comment: take a look at [this](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/9/24/how-to-connect-to-your-local-sql-server-from-inside-docker)

Answer (score 5):

You are (running) a docker-image .. and the (running) docker-image does NOT understand connection strings like

```
localhost

localhost\MyInstance
```

You need the docker-running-image to be able to talk to your local-setup.  You could use the IP address of your local machine.  BUT  fortunately, docker has a built in ALIAS for "the host machine that spawned me (the docker image)".

see:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

> I want to connect from a container to a service on the host The host
> has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We
> recommend that you connect to the special DNS name
> host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by
> the host. This is for development purpose and does not work in a
> production environment outside of Docker Desktop.

Below shows that alias, and how it would be used for a Ms-Sql-Server connection string.

> Data Source=host.docker.internal:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase;

or

> "server=host.docker.internal\MyInstance;database=MyDatabase;"

You may need to use sql authentication as well, to jump "from docker" to your local machine.  (The docker-running-image will NOT understand "integrated security" in the local developer understanding of integrated-security)

You have to treat the docker running images AS ANOTHER MACHINE, so if you have a localhost\MyInstance sql server, you'll have to open up remote tcp connections to it as well.

General rule of thumb.

> A container running on your machine...is NOT like local code..when it
> comes to hitting things like a db-server, local-sftp, etc.

If you do not use sql-authentication, you'll probably get an error like this:

```
Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos authentication.
ErrorCode=InternalError, Exception=Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate).
```

BONUS:

Below is a bookmarked article I have for allowing remote connections to your LOCAL machine.

https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/

Answer (score 0):

The error message already gives you a good hint. The client application that you are spawning in a container named 'console' is either not in the same network as your database instance or your `MSSQL` server is rejecting remote connections.

See Matt. G's [comment](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/9/24/how-to-connect-to-your-local-sql-server-from-inside-docker) how to configure `MSSQL` to accept connections from remote clients.

Because you didn't specify a network when executing `docker run` the container is implicitly connected to your host by a bridge network interface. You can inspect the IP address of a running container with:

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name>
# more verbose:
# docker inspect <container_name>
```

You should also double check your connection string to actually point to the system hosting your database. In your case probably the IP address of your physical computer/docker host.